# Sorting a vector of vectors by second column

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort a `vector<vector<int>>` by the second column.

The function where the problem is:

```
bool SortSecCol( const vector<int>& v1,const vector<int>& v2 )
{
    return v1[1] < v2[1];
}

void SortingSearch(domain &d)
    {
        for (auto &pos : d.Position)                 // Check if bound limits has changed.  If so, adjust bound limits.
        {
            d.lb = min(d.lb, pos - d.delta * 0.5);
            d.ub = max(d.ub, pos + d.delta * 0.5);
        }

        vec3<double> length = d.ub - d.lb;           // calculate length of domain

        double c_size = d.kappa * d.h;                                 // set cell size = kappa * eta * h_initial

        vec3<long> c_n = cast<long>(ceil(length / c_size));         // determine number of cells in each direction

        std::vector<std::vector<long>> c_pidx;                      // cell particle index array
        c_pidx.resize(c_n.x * c_n.y * c_n.z);                       // resize cell array and initialise to 0

        for (long i=0, imax=d.Position.size(); i<imax; ++i)           // for each particle position:
        {
            vec3<long> c_pos = cast<long>(floor((d.Position[i] - d.lb) / c_size));         // determine cell position
            long c_idx = cell_idx(c_pos, c_n);                                          // determine cell index
            c_pidx[c_idx].emplace_back(i);                                              // store particle index in cell

            d.ParticleCellID[i].emplace_back(i);
            d.ParticleCellID[i].emplace_back(c_idx);
        }


        sort(d.ParticleCellID.begin(), d.ParticleCellID.end(), SortSecCol);


        // Displaying the 2D vector after sorting
        std::cout << "The Vector after sorting is:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<d.ParticleCellID.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<2 ;j++)
            {
                std::cout << d.ParticleCellID[i][j] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

        }

    }
```

The problem is that the vector is returning unsorted after that, in the original order. I am not sure what I am missing here.

The vector is quite long (16K rows with 2 columns each) part of it is:

```
356 41 
357 47 
358 42 
359 23
```

When I sort the output is exactly the same as the input

While what I want to do is:

```
359 23 
356 41 
358 42 
357 47
```

I also created this to check it and here it works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> VectorToSort{{0,11},{1,7},{2,8},{3,18}};

bool SortSecCol( const vector<int>& v1,const vector<int>& v2 )
{
    return v1[1] < v2[1];
}

int main()
{
    sort(VectorToSort.begin(), VectorToSort.end(), SortSecCol);

    // Displaying the 2D vector after sorting
    std::cout << "The Vector after sorting is:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<VectorToSort.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<2 ;j++)
        {
            std::cout << VectorToSort[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 7 
2 8 
0 11 
3 18
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please provide a sample input, expected output and the output you got

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you're not showing us.

Comment: `return v1[1] < v2[1];` you may want to throw an exception if either of the vectors don't have a size of 2 or greater.

Comment: @drescherjm accessing offset larger or equal vector size is UB. Calling SortSecCol with vectors shorter then 2 should be documented as UB as well. That should be fair enough, exception is not needed.

Comment: It could also be that you're sorting a copy of the vector you're actually trying to sort...

Comment: You may wish to check `v1.size()` and `v2.size()` first, and return something if either (or both) are less than `2`.   Only when you know both sizes are `2` or more, check `v1[1] < v2[2]`.

Comment: I have edited the first post. When I'm trying it outside my program the method I have above works. So maybe it has something to do with the way I populate the vector?

Comment: Why do you `sort(d.ParticleCellID.begin(), d.ParticleCellID.end(), SortSecCol);` when your vector is `c_pdix` here: `std::vector<std::vector<long>> c_pidx;`

Comment: This is part of a nearest neighbour search function. The domain is devided into cells and the vector c_pdix contains the particles for each cell. This is part of my old algorithm. Now I want to use the other vector - ParticleCellID- (that contains the particle ID and the cell ID only) in order to first re-order the particles in the domain based on the cells that they belong and then perform the NNS.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted above should work and do what you want, assuming `d.ParticleCellID` contains vectors, which have at least 2 elements in them. 
Otherwise element access operator (operator[]) in `SortSecCol` will throw an exception

Comment: It should work yes (and it works when I tried it outside my main program), I think I'm doing something wrong with the way I populate the vector, or I'm missing something obvious. I updated the first post to include the function where I try to sort the vector.

Comment: Your code looks good. I don't understand the whole logic inside ```SortingSearch``` function, but the way you populate the vector should be fine, assuming ```d.ParticleCellID``` is large enough (I think it is, it's confirmed by your output).  Maybe ```d.ParticleCellID``` gets modified in another thread? Try setting a breakpoint inside SortSecCol to make sure it's getting called with the values you expect

Comment: d.ParticleCellID.size() returns with size 0 even though I can print th elements of the vector. Not sure why though, probably that's the problem, the vector is not being used anywhere else at the moment. d.ParticleCellID[i].size() returns 2 as expected.

Comment: Initially I had the same assumption, but if vector size is 0 how could you print the vector content in ```SortingSearch``` function under comment ```Displaying the 2D vector after sorting```?

Answer (score 0):

okay, the problem was that I was just reserving the memory for the vector with vector.reserve(number). When I resized it to the number of particles I had with vector.resize() everything worked perfectly.